# Are questions about ergonomy, health issues of long work with computer allowed on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Are questions about ergonomic health issues with computer work allowed on Stack Overflow? If not, then where can such questions can be asked?

I think issues like vision disabilities, sedentary working style, right position on desk, etc. are important issues for programmers.

Comment: not here for sure

Comment: No, Stack Overflow is not the place for them.

Comment: Maybe it could fit on [Personal Productivity](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but you might check their meta first...

Comment: No, Stack Overflow is coding question. Although i do think it would a good area on the site, to help those who use it. I'd probably use Yahoo! Answers.

Comment: @JoeJoe2416 Regarding Yahoo Answers: I am not intrested in opinon of `average american teenager`. I want to know let's call it `setup` of programmers and software developers, who spent long time not on watching stopid movies, porn, but working, more precisly coding, designing.

Comment: @andi Firstly, I'm British. Secondly, I thought you wanted opinions?

Comment: @andi You can use http://area51.stackexchange.com/ for opening a seperate stack site for health related issues

Comment: @JoeJoe2416 I wanted opinions of provesionals like me (I guess: we) not the general Internet audience:)

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/31587/what-environmental-factors-do-you-believe-contribute-to-productivity

Comment: @bfavaretto That post was closed in December 2011. It has also been deleted, since it is not a good question for our site and does not meet the criteria for historical locking. It should not be used as an example of what Programmers is about - please see our About page and Help Center for a description of what is and is not on-topic.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I didn't say it was, but I understand I could have been more clear. I posted the link to point the user to existing content about the topic. I thought the OP would figure it's not on topic on programmers because it's closed.

Answer (score 17):

I think [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) is the best option in the SE network of sites.

Comment: Definitely, in fact questions on the topic [have been asked already.](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6772/what-should-i-look-for-when-buying-a-desk-and-chair-for-computer-work)

Comment: The meta discussion on the topic from TWP: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1853/is-ergonomics-on-topic

Answer (score 10):

Questions about ergonomics and working conditions are off-topic for stackoverflow.

Based on the Help center of [Personal Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) those type of questions could fit there.

> Personal Productivity Stack Exchange is for people wanting to improve their personal productivity. If you have a question about...
>
> - achieving a productivity workflow, using techniques like GTD, Covey, Pomodoro, etc.
> - fighting procrastination by getting energetic and motivated
> - workflow
> - ergonomics
> - effective sleep habits and the entire sleep-wake transition
> - learning, memory and creativity

They have a tag [ergonomics](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ergonomics)

For the health issue part they redirect to [Physical Fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/) which I don't think is a good candidate for your type of question.

If you have health issues in relation to the ergonomic condition of your workplace go see your physician.

Answer (score 7):

**Not** Programmers.SE.

While questions of this nature have been asked on Programmers.SE in the past, they are routinely closed there.

The reasoning being that while it does concern us, it is not a question that a programmer has expert information in (any more than we have expert information on the best snack foods to eat at one's desk).  For a question to be appropriate to ask on P.SE it needs to draw from our expert programing and design experience and other aspects that are in our professional capacity - ergonomics are not part of our expert field of experience.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6488/40980